# DKIM file not found with Rspamd and a DKIM selector map

Tags: dkim, rspamd

I am running into an error with Rspamd where my dkim signing file is not being found. The exact error message is `dkim_module_load_key_format: cannot load dkim key /var/lib/rspamd/dkim/mydomain.com.dkim.key: cannot stat key file: '/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/mydomain.com.dkim.key' No such file or directory`

It cannot find the file because no such file exists in my `/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/` directory. The only file in that directory is a dkim key with the selector `23211201`. This means, as per my configuration, it should check a file named: `/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/mydomain.com.23211201.key`, however this is not happening.

I have rspamd configured to look for the dkim keys from the `dkim_selectors.map`. Here is the complete configuration file

```shell
# /etc/rspamd/local.d/dkim_signing.conf

path = "/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/$domain.$selector.key";
selector_map = "/etc/rspamd/dkim_selectors.map";
```

The map:

```
# /etc/rspamd/dkim_selectors.map

mydomain.com 23211201
```

I check the permissions on the lib folder and the _rspamd user has read access to that directory. I just created a new dkim key with the selector `dkim` and everything is working as it should. This means the issue is really with the `dkim_selectors.map` file. Maybe there is a default setting for the selector that I need to overwrite? (don't think so since it is not in the rspamd documentation)

What could be going wrong?